# unexpected warning when calling tf2 models using dictionary and for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, dictionary

In Tensorflow V2, when I call tf models inside a dictionary, it yields a warning. This is the dictionary of models:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 import numpy as np

width = 128
height = 128
nchannels = 10
nclasses = 5

models = {   
    'MobileNetV2': tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2,                                                      
    'DenseNet121': tf.keras.applications.DenseNet121,
    'DenseNet169': tf.keras.applications.DenseNet169,
    'DenseNet201': tf.keras.applications.DenseNet201,
    'InceptionResNetV2': tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2,
    'InceptionV3': tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3,
    'MobileNet': tf.keras.applications.MobileNet,
    'Xception': tf.keras.applications.Xception,
    'NASNetLarge': tf.keras.applications.NASNetLarge
    }


for name, arch in models.items():

   inp = np.random.rand(1, width, height, nchannels)
   print(inp.shape) 

   model_arch = arch(input_shape=[width, height, nchannels],
                                                   include_top=False,
                                                   weights=None)
  
   model_classification = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nclasses)

   model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    model_arch,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    model_classification])

   res = model.predict(inp)
   print(name, res.shape)
```

And this is the warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:7 out of the last 7 calls to <function 
Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x0000019FA812C790> 
triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number 
of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) 
passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of 
tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), 
@tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument 
shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to 
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization
/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs
/python/tf/function for  more details.
```

How can I avoid the warning? What is the proper way to train multiple tf models on the same dataset?

Comment: When you say "apply" do you mean "predict the labels of the dataset and check the accuracy of each pretrained model", or "train each model with the given dataset and compare the accuracies obtained"?

Comment: I mean to say, "train each model with the given dataset and compare the accuracies obtained"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from multiple model initializations at once inside the `models` dictionary definition. Since you are going to train one model at a time, it is better to defer the model initialization to the inner loop over the models. Adding one dense layer for classification, your model definition could look like this:

```py
N_CLASSES = 48  # Define your own, based on your dataset!

models = {
    'VGG16': tf.keras.applications.VGG16,
             ....
    'VGG19': tf.keras.applications.VGG19  
    }

for name, arch in models.items():
   # You may have to define a custom input size, according yo tour dataset.
   #  Use  arch(input_size=(WIDTH, HEIGHT, N_CHANNELS)) for that.
   model_arch = arch()
   model_classification = tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_CLASSES)
   
   model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        model_arch,
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        model_classification
   ])
        
   # Training loop, including the data pipeline
   # Stop training, measure accuracy and store model.
   #   -> Next iteration will erase whatever is not stored.
```

**IMPORTANT!** You have to go through the training loop (e.g.: `model.fit(train_data)`) in order to avoid the warning. Otherwise Tensorflow will still warn you that you're being very inefficient when generating an entire model just to run a single prediction (what your code does).

Comment: do you mean to write `tf.keras.applications.VGG16` instead of `tf.keras.applications.VGG16()` in the dictionary?

Comment: i defined and initialized the network layers under the for loop as you have commented out in your code

Comment: yeap, that is basically the change. The dictionaru will hold the functions you will call inside the for loop to initialize the models. Inside the loop you will call them sequentially (one at a time)

Comment: TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <function keras_modules_injection.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000002AFE08F3378>

Comment: `model_arch = arch()`

Comment: Can you list all the applications you're using? Can you share the rest of the code you're using to train them? I updated the code a bit.

Comment: please see my edited question for `full` code i'm running now. It is still yielding the same warning after predicting for the first 7 models

Comment: Ok, the warning is triggered because you are creating a model, running a simple prediction and flushing the model. Tensorflow just warns you that you're being very inefficient by doing this. If, instead of just running a simple prediction, you train each of the models (e.g.: by calling model.fit(train_data)), the warning should disappear.

Comment: training is necessary but another issue is occurring while training, even for a single model https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63129349