# How to solve, tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.random.seed(4213)

data = np.random.randint(low=1,high=29, size=(500, 160, 160, 10)) 
labels = np.random.randint(low=0,high=5, size=(500, 160, 160)) 
nclass = len(np.unique(labels))
print (nclass)

samples, width, height, nbands = data.shape


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=421)

print (X_train.shape)
print (y_train.shape)

arch = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(input_shape=[width, height, nbands],
                      include_top=False,
                      weights=None)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(arch)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nclass))

model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
    

model.fit(X_train,
          y_train,                                 
          epochs=3,
          batch_size=32,
          verbose=2)


res = model.predict(X_test)
print(res.shape)
```

When running the above code for `semantic segmentation` I get Exception has occurred:

```py
InvalidArgumentError
 Incompatible shapes: [32,160,160] vs. [32]
     [[node Equal (defined at c...:38) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1815]


tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError
```

Comment: what line is generating the error?

Comment: `model.fit` , `verbose=2` is generating the error

Comment: You should post the complete error message when dealing with errors in Stackoverflow

Comment: As mentioned in the posted answer, your data is for image segmentation, but your model has the structure for image classification. You should pick a model for that purpose, not VGG16. There are many papers out there discussing neural image segmentation (e.g. see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.05566)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue comes from the size of the last layer (to avoid these mistakes it is always desirable to use python constants for `N_IMAGES`, `WIDTH`, `HEIGHT`, `N_CHANNELS` and `N_CLASSES`):

#### For image classification

You should assign one single label to each image. Try switching `labels`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.random.seed(4213)

N_IMAGES, WIDTH, HEIGHT, N_CHANNELS = (500, 160, 160, 10)
N_CLASSES  = 5

data = np.random.randint(low=1,high=29, size=(N_IMAGES, WIDTH, HEIGHT, N_CHANNELS)) 
labels = np.random.randint(low=0,high=N_CLASSES, size=(N_IMAGES)) 
#...
```

#### For semantic segmentation

Make sure your classifier (last layers of the network) is sized accordingly. In this case you need 1 class per pixel:

```py
#...
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(arch)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(width * height))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape([width , height]))
#...
```

This is the simplest you can get. Instead, you can set up multiple deconvolution layers to act as classifier, or you can even flip the `arch` architecture over and use it to generate the classification results. Orthogohally, you can perform `one_hot` encoding on the labels and thus expand them by a factor of `N_CLASSES`, effectively multiplying the number of neurons in the last layer.

Comment: That's an entirely different question! You should either close this question and ask a new one, or modify it accordingly. Do you have any references for semantic segmentation?